# Android Multiple Notification sending same data on clicking

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

Notification in android taking same intent on clicking.
I am sending notifications after installing the theme. Consider I install 4 themes and 4 notifications appear in Notification window, but when I click on each notification it will launch perticular activity but the intent is having the same data for each intent.

my code goes like this

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
void sendInstalledNotification(String fileName, String packageName) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String name = "";
    try {
        name += fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("NewThemeChooser", "Invalid Package name");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    name += " Installed";
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher_9, name , System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext , ThemeInfo.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("apkid", packageName);
    bundle.putBoolean("isApplied", false);
    intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, name, "Click to Apply Theme", pendingIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    Log.d("NewThemeChooser__:ThemeChangeReceiver" , "hascode : " + packageName.hashCode() + " installed " + packageName);
    notificationManager.notify(packageName.hashCode(), notification);

}
```

and I am printing intent data in onCreate of  ThemeInfo activity as

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
    apkid = bundle.getString("apkid");
    isApplied = bundle.getBoolean("isApplied", false);

    System.out.println("NewThemeChooser__:bundle apkid "  +  apkid );
```

The result I am getting in logs is

```
D/NewThemeChooser__:ThemeChangeReceiver( 4423): hascode : -186637114 installed com.test.theme.MiCrease
D/NewThemeChooser__:ThemeChangeReceiver( 4423): hascode : 2106806482 installed com.test.theme.iPhone
D/NewThemeChooser__:ThemeChangeReceiver( 4423): hascode : -1413669305 installed com.test.theme.Simpsons
D/NewThemeChooser__:ThemeChangeReceiver( 4423): hascode : -2146296452 installed com.test.theme.AnnaTheme
I/System.out( 4423): NewThemeChooser__:bundle apkid com.test.theme.MiCrease
I/System.out( 4423): NewThemeChooser__:bundle apkid com.test.theme.MiCrease
I/System.out( 4423): NewThemeChooser__:bundle apkid com.test.theme.MiCrease
I/System.out( 4423): NewThemeChooser__:bundle apkid com.test.theme.MiCrease
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same issue, and the problem is that Android is being a little too smart and giving you the same `PendingIntent`s instead of new ones. From the **[docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)**:

> A common mistake people make is to create multiple `PendingIntent` objects with `Intent`s that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different `PendingIntent` each time. This does not happen. The parts of the `Intent` that are used for matching are the same ones defined by `Intent.filterEquals`. If you use two `Intent` objects that are equivalent as per `Intent.filterEquals`, then you will get the same `PendingIntent` for both of them.

Modify your code as follows to supply a unique `requestCode`:

```
// ...
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, packageName.hashCode(), intent, 0);
// ...
```

This will ensure that a unique `PendingIntent` is used, as opposed to the same one.

Note that `hashCode()` may not be unique, so if possible use another unique integer as the `requestCode`.

Comment: Actually I had got this fix earlier only but didn't update. thanks @Oleg

Answer (score 0):

Used this code which worked for me.

```
      int requestCode = new Random().nextInt();
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, 
      notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```