# Launch activity from multiple notifications overrides the previous intent

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

```
public static void showNotification(Context ctx, int value1, String title, String message, int value2){

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, ActivityMain.class);
    int not_id = Utils.randInt(1111, 9999);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("key_1", value1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("key_2", value2);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(ctx.getApplicationContext());
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent notifPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificationManager.notify(not_id, createNotification(ctx, notifPendingIntent, title, message));
}
```

This is my code to send and display a `notification`. I send this from a service. As you see there are 2 extra values that I send with the intent (`key_1` and `key_2`); When I click a notification I should open the activity and see the `value1` and `value2` of the keys.

The problem is: if another notification arrives before I open any of them, `value1` and `value2` are overridden. For instance:

- first notification sends `foo` and `bar`

  - second notification sends `faz` and `baz`
  - third notification send `fubar` and `fobaz`

So I will have 3 notifications in the bar. Now, whatever notification I click, first, second, third, I will see the values sent by the last one `fubar` and `fobaz`. 
What I want is when I click on a specific notification, the activity display the values sent by that notification.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're using `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`:

> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent.

This is what is replacing your `extra` data with the data from the last intent.

Instead pass 0 for PendingIntent's default behavior here:

```
PendingIntent notifPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, silly me, I have only used `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` and `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`

Comment: Ok, I have tried your solution but now only the first extra is kept ignoring the other ones! I didn't noticed that first. Any other idea? so I can accept the answer....

Comment: @AlexAndro I think the root of your problem lies in the fact that you need to vary the contents of your intents so that `.filterEquals()` doesn't filter out one another because they are so similar. See these answers - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3009690/745750 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17200687/745750. Just changing the values of your `extras` is not enough to trick the `.filterEquals()` method.

Comment: I found that the secret is to use a DIFFERENT `PendingIntent`. I'm gonna give you the credit anyway, for good url you provided, even the hint was into another answer from that question and also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297710/create-new-pending-intent-every-time-in-android